# Cities XL Memory leak Fix?

Tags: technical-issues, cities-xl

There is some kind of memory issue with Cities XL which makes the game slower as the population increases. There have been various workarounds (like going back to the map screen and then back to the game once in a while). Is there any fix/patch for that?

Comment: Have you checked the publisher's website?  If there's any fix for it, chances are good that's where it's going to be.

Comment: They have made a patch, but that didn't fix this issue.

Comment: Was the patch to address that specific issue, or other things?

Comment: I would contact the publisher.

Comment: The didn't made a patch for that. They have said it themselves on their own forum. I have uninstalled the game, will post the workarounds I found here and there as a wiki answer.